# How to remove the bracket in the output of Table[1,{10}]?

Tags: list-manipulation

I tried `Table[1, {10}] //. {x_} :> x` , but it doesn't work. The output is still `{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}`

Comment: `Sequence @@ Table[1, {10}]` or `Table[1, {10}] //. {x__} :> x` (Note use of [`BlankSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlankSequence.html) rather than just [`Blank`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html))

Comment: Is it possible you're looking to display the output with [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row.html)?

Comment: You can't remove brackets.  Mathematica does not allow one to enter `1,1,1,1` as it is syntax error. It must be a list. But may be I missing something about this question as you did explain what the context is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Row[ Riffle[Table[1, {10}], ","]]
```

output

> 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1

**update:** as   jjc385  suggested  you can use Row's second option to insert a separator between the elements

```
Row[Table[1,{10}],","]
```

the output does not change

**update2:** as Nasser suggested

```
TextString[Table[1, {10}], ListFormat -> {"", ",", ""}]
```

Comment: How about `Row[ list, "," ]`?

Comment: yep that's better, i  forgot row can add a separator

Comment: The confusing thing, is that we do not know how OP wants to use the result.  Row is just formatting object and can't be used in computation. It was not clear to me OP was looking for just formatting. But may be they were.

Comment: he seems to know  patterns, surely he knows he need lists for computation. I think he just wants to show some result without brackets

Comment: "I think he just wants to show some result without brackets" In this case, another option can be to use `ListFormat` as in `TextString[Table[1, {10}], ListFormat -> {"", ",", ""}]` which gives `1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1`

Comment: @Nasser cool, do you mind if i add it to the answer? for  clarity

Comment: sure, feel free to do that.

Comment: @Nasser I'm still curious about how to achieve this in computation? For example Sum[i[1] + i[2], Row[Table[{i[k], 1, 2}, {k, 1, 2}], ","]] doesn't work.